# How to increase STS (Spring Tool Suite) memory size?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am trying to increase heap size (memory) for the spring tool suite as I am getting out of memory.

If I increase from Xmx from 768m to 1024m I get the error "Failed to Create Java Virtual Machine".

If I revert Xmx to 768m it works fine but I get OOM (Out of Memory). I have STS 2.9.2. OS is win7.

This is currently what I have in sts.ini at the moment.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
com.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss1m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

what should I change? Please advise.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how much physical memory do you have? (Are you set up for 64-bit working?)

Comment: Yes, there is limitation in 32 bit case. But try to (800~900).

Comment: There is also a garbage collection feature in STS, which is accessible, once activated from preferences,  through a small UI-element.  The amount being used is displayed as well to aid in managing the heap manually.

Comment: Please note that Spring Tool Suite is now is now deprecated and only It will receive maintenance updates until mid of 2019. Use Spring Tools 4. More details here https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 3):

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-
1740
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xmx1024m
```

You should change only Xmx.
Here I am using Xmx1024m means STS is assigned with 1 GB Ram
And Xmx4G means 4GB RAM.
You can check the heap status as

Open sts in Windows menu select Preferences then from General tab mark show heap status option.