# how to run sonar lint on Spring tool suite

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, spring-tool-suite

I need help in running sonar lint in Spring tool suite

I have installed sonar plugin, created a sonar-project.properties file placed in root level, my project is developed in Maven

unable to run sonar in spring tool suite, GC reached out of memory error and my spring tool suite is getting hanged

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by increasing max jvm heap in sts.ini file.
Can you try increasing max heap size.
For more information on how to increase max heap please refer -
[How to increase STS (Spring Tool Suite) memory size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041147/how-to-increase-sts-spring-tool-suite-memory-size)